# Running vim with custom vimrc does not load colorscheme

Tags: vimrc

Inside my home dir I have 2 `.vimrc` files (`.vimrc` and `.vimrc2`). They both use the same coloscheme `badwolf.vim`.
Location of colorscheme is `~/.vim/colors/badwolf.vim`
If I execute:

```
vim
```

everything looks as expected.

But if I do:

```
vim -u .vimrc2
```

I get a lot of error messages and colorscheme does not load.

```
Error detected while processing /home/user1/.vimrc2[6]../home/user1/.vim/colors/badwolf.vim[2337]..function <SNR>3_acquire_theme_data[29]..<SNR>3_register_default_theme:
...
E121: Undefined variable: s:fg_aqua
line  654:
E121: Undefined variable: s:fg_purple
line  655:
E121: Undefined variable: s:fg_purple
...
```

my `.vimrc2` is:

```
set relativenumber
set encoding=UTF-8
set background=dark
colorscheme badwolf
```

I tried to use runtime vars in the `.vimrc2`, but it did not help:

```
set rtp+="/home/user1/.vim/"
set rtp+="/home/user1/.vim/colors/"
```

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-) Could you tell us how the badwolf colorscheme is installed (as a plugin or as a file in `~/.vim/colors`) where is the `badwolf.vim` file in your `~/.vim` hierarchy?

Comment: as a file under `~/.vim/colors/badwolf.vim`

Comment: Also I tried to load the current `.vimrc` with `vim -u .vimrc` and I get the same issue.

Comment: Try `vim -Nu .vimrc2`

Comment: Can you tell us from where you got `badwolf.vim`. From the stack trace it looks like it has more than 2300 line but the GitHub version only has 670.

Comment: It works! Thanks!

Comment: Vivian, it is a custom colorscheme based on badwolf and other one. I did it by myself. Matt comment worked for me. My bad! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'm glad your problem is solved :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Matt and Vivian => the answer is:

`vim -Nu .vimrc2`

Ref:
The command "set nocompatible" in Vim is used to disable compatibility mode, which makes Vim behave more like Vi, the original Unix visual text editor. By default, Vim starts in compatible mode to maintain compatibility with Vi, but by issuing "set nocompatible" in your Vim configuration (typically in your .vimrc file), you're telling Vim to use its own enhanced functionality and features.

Comment: An explanation of WHY that extra `-N` solves your problem, with pointers to the relevant doc, would be welcome.

Comment: Note that 'by default' is not perfectly accurate. If you have no `vimrc` file Vim will source `$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim` that set the `nocompatible` option.

Comment: Feel free to accept your answer in two days. It allow the question to rest :-)

Comment: More importantly, _unless you use `-u` having a vimrc makes Vim nocompatible_. That’s why `vim` works but `vim -u ~/.vimrc` doesn’t.